# Can I program a QUAD SPI Chip with a standard SPI microcontroller?

Tags: serial, spi, programming, flash, programmer

I have to program a MX25L12835 Quad SPI chip. This is a Quad SPI serial flash. Is it possible to program this using an arduino? Can this be used as a simple 1 channel SPI or can quad SPI interface fall back to regular SPI? Or do I need a microcontroller that supports quad SPI?

Do I need to do anything special to connect the flash chip?

Comment: I feel compelled to clarify some terminology here. Referring to the referenced part as a Quad SPI is misleading at best. This part does not have four SPI ports on it. Instead it is a part with a SPI iterface that is capable of transferring data in certain modes on a single serial path, a dual I/O capability of serial data 2-bits at a time and a quad I/O capability of serial dats 4-bits at a time. The idea behind dual and quad I/O parts is that data blocks can be clocked in or out of the part 2 or 4 times faster than the legacy single I/O SPI interface can sustain.

Comment: The nomenclature is undoubtedly misleading, but Quad SPI is the terminology used in the flash memory industry for chips that support the 4-bit protocol. It does not refer to the number of buses, but to the width of a single bus.

Comment: @ScottWinder - A quick Google search and looking at various SPI Flash chip data sheets seems to indicate that "Dual I/O" and "Quad I/O" terms are the terms used by the component vendors. On the otherhand the "Dual SPI" and "Quad SPI" terms are being carelessly being used by providers of IP that is used to control or interface with the multi I/O types of SPI Flash parts. For example, I found references to this in IP provided from Altera and Xilinx FPGA vendors and in a processor from Freescale.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - I agree that the IP vendors are probably the root cause of the nomenclature, but my customers never ask me for "Quad I/O"; it's always "Quad SPI" (or QSPI). Evil though it may be, the industry has adopted that use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi-SPI memories require specific commands to invoke multi-SPI transfers. Simply refrain from using these commands and the device will work correctly in single-SPI mode.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the information on the [product information page](http://www.macronix.com/QuickPlace/hq/PageLibrary4825740B00298A3B.nsf/h_Index/6F878CF760C559BD482576E00022E6CC/?OpenDocument&EPN=MX25L12835F), yes, you can.

If you have a specific question after reviewing the datasheet and application notes, then come back here and edit your question.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so. I attempted to connect it to my Raspberry Pi, but the chip never showed up as a connected device on SPI. I plan to put a logic analyzer this time and try again.

Comment: You can initially send JEDEC RDID command to read manufacturer information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use SPI command to communicate with QSPI flash devices and it will work without any problem. Obviously you won't get a throughput of a quad device.